# How to call a javascript method when user switches to dyanamically created tab in tabset?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm dynamically creating tabs in my html and I'd now like a feature whereby when the user changes tab it will call a javascript function.

My html is as follows:

```html
<tabset id="MonthsTabset" justified="true"  style="padding-left:175px; padding-right:175px">
  <tab ng-repeat="month in months"
    heading="{{month.name}}"
    active=month.active>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

Now within that tab I'd like something like 'onclick="functionCall()"', so that when the user changes tab a javascript method is called, however, I can't seem to find a way to do this.
Also, I'm not using jquery.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what is wrong with `<tab onClick="function(){alert('clicked');}>"`?

Comment: Already tried and it's nothing doing anything

Comment: Do you get error in console because of `active=month.active` must be `active="{{month.active}}"`?

Comment: No error for that, however, I get an error for function saying it's not defined. Here's the function:  function changeMonth() {
  alert('Here');
 }

Comment: Please show full code with this function

Comment: That is the whole function; I haven't got round to coding it because of this problem i ran in to. Anyway, I fixed it now by changing the function declaration to window.functionname = function(). Thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any errors in console. Also, I think your `active=month.active` must be `active="{{month.active}}"`

```js
function call(tab) {
  alert(tab);
}
```

```css
tab {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<tabset id="MonthsTabset" justified="true" style="padding-left:175px; padding-right:175px">
  <tab ng-repeat="month in months" heading="{{month.name}}" active="{{month.active}}" onClick="call('tab 1')">
    Tab 1
  </tab>
  <tab ng-repeat="month in months" heading="{{month.name}}" active="{{month.active}}" onClick="call('tab 2')">
    Tab 2
  </tab>
</tabset>
```